# How do I have git not track .vscode/ or .gitignore file changes?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just started using vscode editor and when I checked git status I saw that it has the warning of the `.vscode/` file not being tracked. How do I have it ignore this? When I added this to the `.gitignore` file, it then said I made changes to the `.gitignore` file. I always thought that this file would automatically be ignored by git and wouldn't be tracked as its changes should only ever be saved to my local copy?

Answer (score 8):

`.gitignore` is something that *should* be under version control.
This way all people who checkout the project will also be persuaded away from trying to commit their `.vscode/` directory.

`.gitignore` is not specific to your environment, but rather the repository.

---

If you *really* don't want to put this rule in the repo's `.gitignore`, then you can setup a per-user ignore file:

```sh
git config --global core.excludesfile $HOME/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the `.gitignore` file, you can create rules that will only apply to you.

You can use this rule for locally generated files, that you don't expect others to generate, such as files created by your editor.

Open this file called `.git/info/exclude` within the root of your Git repository(project dir) and add your rules.

If you have vim, you can do so with `vi .git/info/exclude`

Any rule you add here will not be checked in, and will only ignore files for your repository.